# Just installed armory + bitcoinQT synced. It takes a total of 40GB of space?

Tags: armory

i just synced bitcoinqt which takes about 20GB and then I installed armory which takes another 20GB. Now thats 40GB in space. Seems like it downloaded the blockchain twice? or is it suppose to take this much space due to armory's setup?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[From the Armory web site, regarding Bitcoin-QT and/or Bitcoind:](https://bitcoinarmory.com/about/armory-and-bitcoin-qt/)

> Regardless of which one you use, it will download the entire blockchain (12-20 GB at the time of this writing).  The latest version of Armory will effectively double that storage requirement ...

Comment: I don't think this answers the question. I've run into the same issue on Ununtu. Armory's leveldb_blkdata is suspiciously similar to the size of the blockchain which I also have; thus the 40GB. Is this normal? Should we expect Armory to consume double the size of the blockchain in storage space?

Comment: The quote in my answer was from the Armory web site, where they state that they will double the storage required: If the blockchain is 20gb, then Armory will require *another* 20gb for a total of 40gb.